# Why do we need partial derivatives?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Partial derivatives are used to find the slope of a three dimensional curve at an angle. But why do we need them? Can't another function be created from the first one which calculates $x$ and $y$ based on $x$ and the angle ($g(x, \theta) = f(\cos(\theta)x,\sin(\theta)x)$), and then derivate that one?

Comment: That's a rather narrow view of partials. Partials are what you use to find the derivative of a function of many variables, when you are considering the effects of just one variable *ceteris paribus*. It's the classic notion of divide and conquer.

Comment: Yes, precisely^